# Changing specific dates into years in attribute table

Tags: attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a shapefile with all the buildings of the region. In the attribute table I have a field containing the date that the individual buildings have been built. I need to count how many buildings have been built in the region in certain years.

How can I change the specific dates (e.g. 15.2.2008) (the field is text form, not numeric) into year (2008)?

I use both QGIS and ArcGIS (ArcInfo), so any tips for either programme would be great.

Comment: What software are you using for this?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a new field containing your year, so you can count on it, and keep the full date for a later use.
Use the function 'right' to fill your new field with the last four characters of your date field (only the year) :

```
right(  "dateField" , 4 )
```

This works with QGIS, but equivalent functions exists in other softwares.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using QGIS because you mention "attribute table", as Pierre states , you can add a new field and populate it with the year.  Another function that is available is YEAR(date):

From the expression dialog:

> **function year**
>
> Extract the year part from a date, or the number of years from an
>   interval.
>
> **Date variant**
>
> Extract the year part from a date or datetime.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> year(date)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> date a date or datetime value
>
> **Examples**
>
> - year('2012-05-12') → 2012